# Mongodb exports fine but complains when importing with the same file the export creates

Tags: mongodb

I see there are quite a few people with exporting an importing a collection/database issues.

When I try to export a collection via:

```
mongodump --db database1 --collection collection1
```

This is perfectly fine. No errors.

But when I try to import the collection that I just exported:

```
mongoimport --db database1 --collection collection1 --file collection1.bson -vvvvv
```

I get:

```
Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character '\u008f' looking for beginning of value
```

I've tried to import/export a different collections and I get:

```
Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character '¡' looking for beginning of value
```

Is there a simple way to fix this other than going through a binary encoded json file to look for `¡` and `\u008f`? Why would mongo allow it to be exported yet complains when trying to import it?

Comment: `mongodump` and then `mongorestore`. `mongoexport` and then `mongoimport.` You need to use the right tool combination.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot more sense